# Check that WiFi is turned on in a React Native iOS app

Tags: ios, react-native, wifi

Do you know how it is possible to check that WiFi is turned on in a React Native iOS app. Due to the aGPS on iOS devices, the WiFi must be turned on in order for our location sensitive app to be able to work effectively and we want to notify the user in cases it is turned off.

Any idea how to achieve this in a React Native app for iOS?

Answer (score 1):

i don't know exactly what are you going to do with WIFI information, but if you want simple information, I use react-native netinfo: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-netinfo#react-native-communitynetinfo 
If you use Expo I recommended this one, network https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/network/